# DotNetOpenAuth - How to add AJAX-style OpenID Selector control

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, openid, dotnetopenauth

I have a MVC 3 Web App in C#, I have installed from NuGet the DotNetOpenAuth library

```
PM> Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth
```

The [download page](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) says that an `AJAX-style OpenID Selector control is included`, but I cannot find instructions on where it is and how to install it on a View.

Could you point me out in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that meant a Webforms control... not relevant for MVC.

A little snooping around and I found this example: https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Creating-an-openid-relying-party-(programatically)
(scroll down to the MVC header).

*UPDATE:* Updated broken link.

Comment: Sorry... meant to add:
So it looks like you'll need to write your own -- true MVC style!

Comment: Updated the URL to the new location.